# How to add brand filter option in admin product grid?

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.x

I need to add brand filter option in the product grid by admin panel.

I have a brand attribute. It is working front end side. But, I need to product search brand wise by admin side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can follow these steps :

1. Go to  **Stores -> Attributes -> Product**
2. Under **Advanced Attribute Properties** of your attribute
   Change **Use in Filter Options** to  Yes  and change **Add to Column Options** to Yes.

Comment: Is need both options enabled? @sami23

Comment: @MasudShaikh yes :D

Comment: @MasudShaikh Tell me if it works

Comment: Ok, I am working on it.

Comment: @sami12 It is working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: @MasudShaikh your welcome :D

Comment: @MasudShaikh brand filter doesn't show up after following the steps above.